# Replace a column value for a select set of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame for which I'd like to replace one column value for a small subset of rows. E.g. given:

```
in_dict = [{ 'what': 'abc', 'num': 42}, {'what': 'abc', 'num': 43}, {'what': 'def', 'num': 99}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(in_dict)
```

which looks like:

```
  what  num
0  abc   42
1  abc   43
2  def   99
```

Using

```
lookup = {'abc': 'xyz'}
```

I want to end up with:

```
  what  num
0  xyz   42
1  xyz   43
2  def   99
```

I can use map, but then I get NaN's for entries not in the lookup table:

```
>>> df['what'] = df['what'].map(lookup)
>>> df
  what  num
0  xyz   42
1  xyz   43
2  NaN   99
```

My actual DataFrame is about 100k items, of which <100 need the update.

What is the most efficient (and ideally pandas-idiomatic) approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `fillna` on the `map`ped Series to fill it with the original:

```
df['what'] = df['what'].map(lookup).fillna(df['what'])
```

But a better option is to use `replace`:

```
df['what'] = df['what'].replace(lookup)
```

Output:

```
  what  num
0  xyz   42
1  xyz   43
2  def   99
```